# Confused about making Django Asynchronous (RealTime)

Tags: django, node.js, real-time, tornado

Better Technology to Make a Django project Asynchronous (RealTime) (using Tornado with django ORM or Node.js  ),

Node.js is really Tough to code.

I followed a tutorial :  Using Django Inside the Tornado Web Server.

[http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2009/sep/15/using-django-inside-tornado-web-server/][1]

Solution :

i've developed a package for django called **django-realtime** . It may be helpful for other devs facing the same issue i have faced before

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-realtime/1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django IMO shouldn't be used as an Asynchronous application, it's not designed for that. If you want a real time application using things like web sockets you'll need to separate your concerns.

I'm building a real time application with Django as the MVC framework for serving the site and any RESTy API calls, Gevent SocketIO as the Web Sockets Server for the real time bit and Redis Pub/Sub (will switch out for ZeroMQ) as the message transport for various different parts of the application to comunicate with the socket server and emit events.

Take a look at https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio. It does have a Django integration component but imo it's a bit magical, I would use it to build a separate web socket server, keep things simple.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to integrate gevent with django

Answer (score 1):

Django and Celery are well working together.
You'll find on the web many infos, but the best places to look are

- the Celery Website : http://www.celeryproject.org/
- the Django-celery module : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery

But using Celery is really not mandatory. Since Django can operate any of the Python modules (or near), you can simple use RabbitMQ (as a broker) and use `amqp` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/amqp) which is a fork of `amqplib` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/amqplib).

Basically, any how-to you'll find about Python + AMQP should work for Django.

Comment: I have release some packages to overcome this issue and hosted a training video :

Please have a look

https://vimeo.com/94808324